# Difference argument passing to method and assignment

Tags: java, arrays, argument-passing, assignment-operator

```
  List<Object[]> d = new ArrayList<Object[]>();

  d.add({"A"});//compile error
  Object [] arr = {"A"};//valid
```

I always thought that last 2 rows make equally operations and regulated by similar rules.

Who can it explain?

Comment: How do you find these answers?

Comment: Well I just answered that one :). Otherwise, if you have a compiler error, take the generic parts and search for them. If that doesn't help, try to express in words what isn't working. Here it's `array initialization`, for example.

Comment: Just to add more info to these answers, d.add(new Object[]{"A"}); will work without any error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I always thought that last 2 rows make equally operations and regulated by similar rules.

You were wrong.

> Who can it explain?

I can't explain why you were wrong, but I can explain the syntax. The final line is valid because it is an initialisation, and initialisations have special syntax. If you had split it into a declaration and an assignment you would have got the same error in the assignment that you got in the second line. That syntax for a value simply does not exist in Java.

Comment: **If you had split it into a declaration and an assignment you would have got the same error in the assignment that you got in the second line.**- helpful remark

Answer (score 2):

It's not about passing arguments to method. You can only use the `{x}` shorthand while initializing an array, such as your valid example. Anywhere else it's invalid. If you need to instantiate an array at a later time after initialization, you need to use `new int[]`.

```
int[] a = {1,2};    // OK

int[] b;
b = {1,2};          // compiler error
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an array initializer as an argument.

Comment: Or as anything else except an array initializer.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case

```
d.add({"A"});//compile error
```

You need to create a new instance of Object[] to serve as the method argument like this:

```
d.add(new Object[]{"A"});
```

In the second case, you create an array of Object. You can also do the similar thing:

```
Object [] arr = new Object[] {"A"};
```

Java lets you do the following because I think it maintains some compatibility with C/C++ array definition in the original design.

```
Object [] arr = {"A"};//valid
```

Comment: It lets you do that because the type is already known from the declaration that's in progress, so specifying it again is redundant. However the type isn't already known in the other contexts, so it is required.